# How can change layout arrangement and animation effects of minicart Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

Is that possible to make new animation effect and layout to mini cart in magento 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible quickly by third-party Mageplaza extension.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-quick-cart/

Thanks
Kapil

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information but is that possible by custom coding?